# How to stop a Splash Screen with a click before the end?

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I created an activity splashScreen in my application.

This works very well with animation is my code :

```
public class SpalshScreenActivity extends Activity {
 private static final int STOPSPLASH = 0;
 private static final long SPLASHTIME = 3000;
 private boolean flagBack = false;

 private final transient Handler splashHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == STOPSPLASH && !flagBack) {
            StartMainActivity();
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
 };

 public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.HideActionBar);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    StartAnimations();
    final Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = STOPSPLASH;
    splashHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, SPLASHTIME);
 }

 private void StartAnimations() {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);
 }

 private void StartMainActivity() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(SpalshScreenActivity.this, MainFragmentActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
 }

 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent evt) {  
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        flagBack = true;
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }}
```

Now I would like to add the ability to click on the screen to stop the SplashScreen.

I tried this way, it works but I think it is not an optimal solution (slow) :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        flagBack = true;
        StartMainActivity();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just set the onclicklistener for the imageview and inside that call whatever you call to end the splashscreen.

Comment: Just a tip: The Android Design guidelines advise against splash screens. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html

Comment: @lopez.mikhael Its written just under the "Designing Help into Your App" section. Basically, it's annoying for the user to get a SplashScreen/or it's useless. Usually, the user is able to discover the features of an app by its own way. But these are only advices.

Comment: Design guidelines are only "guidelines", but yes, I recommend only showing a splash screen once ever to the user, but then every time the user goes to open the app they will love the speed at which it loads. Do not use a splash screen just because you can, use a splash screen to do something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

set an OnClickListener to the activity with the same code as in the onTouchEvent